# TeamCity continues to build projects that have been excluded from my Visual Studio solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, csproj

My Visual Studio 2019 solution contains several projects, some of which I don't want to be built as part of continuous integration.  Specifically, I'm trying to exclude tooling and unit tests.

In Visual Studio, I have created a new solution configuration and unchecked the "Build" box for each project I don't want to be built.

In TeamCity, I have specified the name of the new solution configuration to use.  However, TeamCity continues to attempt to build all projects within the solution.

[I had included screenshots of my solution configuration, TeamCity build configuration, and resulting TeamCity log but I do not have enough reputation to post images apparently.]

From everything I could find so far, unchecking "Build" from the solution configuration used by TeamCity is supposed to exclude that project from building.

Comment: Have you verified in the build log that the configuration is being specified to MSBuild as intended?

Comment: Thank you, yes, the TeamCity log does show that it's using my new solution configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by finally noticing that the TeamCity log was showing the build configuration as "ReleaseCI|Mixed Platforms" instead of "ReleaseCI|Any CPU".  On other projects, I only needed to specify the configuration.  For this project, I apparently have to specify the platform as well.